# How to find the different number in a 2D array by comparing each row?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Outputting the unique number(s) that only this row has, compared to all other rows in a 2D array.
For example:

```
list2d = [ 
    [5,9], 
    [1,5], 
    [1,5,7,8] 
]
```

---

**Basically, this is what I expected:**

```
>When doing for row 0, the output should be [9]  
>When doing for row 1, the output should be []  
>When doing for row 2, the output should be [7,8]
```

---

```
list1 = [5,9]
list2 = [1,5]
list3 = [1,5,8,7]

print(set(list1).difference(list2).difference(list3))
```

---

However, the above method can't be used in a loop, since I don't know how many rows I will have so I can't separate them into multiple lists.

Is there a way to solve it? (better not use additional package)

Comment: I think the example is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
list2d = [
    [5,9],
    [1,5],
    [1,5,7,8]
]


res = [set(lst).difference(*(lst2 for j, lst2 in enumerate(list2d) if j != i)) for i, lst in enumerate(list2d)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{9}, set(), {7, 8}]
```

Alternative:

```
res = []
for i, lst in enumerate(list2d):
    others = (lst2 for j, lst2 in enumerate(list2d) if j != i)
    diff = set(lst).difference(*others)
    res.append(diff)
```

A third alternative is the following, using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

list2d = [
    [5, 9],
    [1, 5],
    [1, 5, 7, 8]
]

counts = Counter(ei for e in list2d for ei in e)

res = []
for lst in list2d:
    lst_counts = Counter(lst)
    res.append([e for e, c in lst_counts.items() if counts[e] == c])

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[9], [], [7, 8]]
```

The overall computational complexity of this last alternative is `O(n)`. Also note this alternative can be implemented using the default dictionary class.